# Is there any way to get Microsoft Edge Web driver pushed to customers?

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am looking for a way to monitor changes to Microsoft Edge Web driver programmatically.
Some possiblities:
      * Would be great if there is an API (REST) to monitor latest available Edge webdriver.
      * Since Edge driver is dependent on windows build version. some information about windows 10 build version in the API would be useful.
      * Or Even better.. Since Edge driver depends on windows 10 build version, is there any chance for the Edge driver to get shipped with windows 10 builds. something like the native calc.exe in the system32 folder...

Any guidance/information would be very helpful.

Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Primary versions of Web Driver can always be found on [dev.microsoftedge.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/). Presently, this includes versions for 10240, 10586, and the *Fast Ring* of the [Windows Insider Program](https://insider.windows.com/). Monitoring that page will give you insight as to when a newer version of Web Driver is available for Edge.

With regards to your other questions:

1. Can we have a REST API to identify latest/supported Web Driver / OS versions
2. Can Web Driver be shipped in Windows 10 directly

I'll reach out to the appropriate team member(s), and see if this is something they've considered.

For the time being, you may be able to infer the machine's build of Windows by leveraging common APIs. For instance, via Node, you could do the following:

```js
require("os").release().match(/\d+$/);
```

Depending on your build of windows, this will return, `[10240]`, `[10586]`, or some newer build number, like `[14379]`. You could then use this to instruct the user as to which version of Web Driver they should download.

Comment: Thanks Sampson, for the temporary solution. But.. Points 1) and 2) will help in building a more robust and autonomous infrastructure ..